Shortcode does not show the values ​in full
I have a problem with the shortcode, it does not show me the values ​​I enter correctly
For example, this shortcode:
function subscribe_link_att($atts) {
    $default = array(
        'link'=>'',
        'title' => ''
);
    $a = shortcode_atts($default, $atts);

    return 'Follow us on <a href="'.$a['link'].'">'.$a['title'].'</a>';
    return ob_get_clean();

}
add_shortcode('subscribe', 'subscribe_link_att');


It shows me this:
Follow us on <a href="">’sqsqsc</a>

Current Wordpress version: 6.7.1
